# android blob pdf error not returning

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to store a some data fields and a pdf.I have created two classes ,the first is a DatabaseHandler which does all my basic database stuffs and to refer to a row of the database i have created a class myHelper which creates a record/row object having each data element that i require.The problem that i am facing is that i need to store a pdf inside the database.I have done "       values.put(KEY_pdf, row.get_pdf());       " and it gives me an error "      cannot resolve the method put() " and as obvious reasons i have declared the type as String.In my App ,What i want is that when i add some button in my activity after  inputting the required sem,year,branch values from theuser,i need the pdf to be displayed that is the reason i have created the get() method for pdf,but this logic doesnt seem to work out or am i missing something.Urgent help.Moreover any improvements suggested are highly appreciable.

myHelper.java

```
package com.DataBaseHandler;

import java.sql.Blob;

/**
 *
 */

    public class myHelper {

        //private variables
        int _id;
        String _branch;
        int _year;
        int _sem;
        Blob _pdf;

        // Empty constructor
        public myHelper(){

        }
        // constructor
        public myHelper(int id, String _branch, int _year,int _sem,Blob _pdf){
            this._id = id;
            this._branch = _branch;
            this._year = _year;
            this._sem = _sem;
            this._pdf = _pdf;
        }
        // getting ID
        public int getID(){
            return this._id;
        }
        public void setID(int _id){
            _id =  this._id;
        }

        // getting branch
        public String get_branch(){
            return this._branch;
        }
        public void set_branch(String _branch){
            _branch = this._branch;
        }

        // setting year
        public int get_year(){
            return this._year;
        }
        public void set_year(int _year){
            _year = this._year;
        }

        // getting sem
        public int get_sem(){
            return this._sem;
        }
        public void set_sem(int _sem){
            _sem = this._sem;
        }

        // setting pdf
        public Blob get_pdf(){
          return this._pdf;
        }
        public void set_pdf(Blob _pdf){
            _pdf = this._pdf;
        }
}

DataBaseHandler.java
package com.DataBaseHandler;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 *
 */
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "infinity";
    private static final String TABLE_SYLLABUS = "syllabus";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_BRANCH = "branch";
    private static final String KEY_YEAR = "year";
    private static final String KEY_SEM = "sem";
    private static final String KEY_pdf = "pdf";

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SYLLABUS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_BRANCH + " TEXT," + KEY_YEAR + " NUMBER,"
                + KEY_SEM + " NUMBER," + KEY_pdf + " BLOB," + ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SYLLABUS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
    public void addRow(myHelper row) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_BRANCH, row.get_branch() );
        values.put(KEY_YEAR,row.get_year());
        values.put(KEY_SEM, row.get_sem());
        values.put(KEY_pdf, row.get_pdf());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

}
```

Comment: Do i need to reframe my question or is it impossible for people at stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `Blob` into a byte array to be able to use the [`put` function with a `byte[]` parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5b%5d%29):

```java
Blob blob = row.get_pdf();
values.put(KEY_pdf, blob.getBytes(0, blob.length()));
```

Comment: it gives java.sql.SQLException at "blob.length()"

Comment: Where did you get the blob from?

Comment: i declared it locally in the same class

Comment: moreover row.get_pdf() function returns the required pdf.

Comment: I meant, how did you create that `Blob` object?